# VBS to split one column in two columns

Tags: split, vbscript

Let's say for example, i have one column filled with names, each name in one cell.

```
    First_Name_1 Last_Name_1
    First_Name_2 Last_Name_2
    First_Name_3 Last_Name_4
```

First name and last name are separated by space.
How can i split this column in two columns, using Visual Basic Script so that i will have First_Name in one column and Last_name in a column next to it?

Already tried this code, but can't manage to make it work.

```
    objExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns(4).Select
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    'Search for position of space within the cell
    SplitPoint = InStrRev(ActiveCell, " ", -1, vbTextCompare)
    'Put the last name in the column next to the source column
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = Trim(Left(ActiveCell, SplitPoint))
    'Replace the source column with the first name
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0) = Trim(Mid(ActiveCell, SplitPoint))
    Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Excel has a `TextToColumns()` function that can do what you're looking for with a single function call.

```
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns(4).TextToColumns , , , , , , , True
```

Might make more sense with the params shown. Your data is space-delimited so we just need to set the 8th param to `True`. The rest can be omitted to accept the defaults.

```
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns(4).TextToColumns _
    , _        ' Destination (optional, defaults to source)
    , _        ' DataType (optional, defaults to xlDelimited)
    , _        ' TextQualifier (optional, defaults to xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote)
    , _        ' ConsecutiveDelimiter
    , _        ' Tab-delimited? (optional, defaults to False)
    , _        ' Semicolon-delimited? (optional, defaults to False)
    , _        ' Comma-delimited? (optional, defaults to False)
    True       ' Space-delimited?
```

Comment: How to give other characters as delimiters like | or +?

Answer (score -1):

You are not moving to the next cell of the range. Add:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
```

I'd add something to check for double spaces (remove one), no spaces and double names or initials (Mary Lou Smith, John M. Lewis).