# Texttocolumn Excel using VBS

Tags: vbscript

Quick question from my end about using the Text to columns function in Excel via VBS.

I have the following code below but I can't get it to run.
It is getting stuck in the last line of code, any thoughts on how to pass it to excel?

```
Dim strfilepathcqr
strfilepathcqr = "C:FilepathExample"

Dim objExcel
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim objWb
Set objWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strfilepathcqr)

Set ws = objWB.Worksheets(1)

Set objRange = ws.range("AY2:AY83221")
Set objRange2 = ws.Range("AY2")

objRange.select
ObjRange.TextToColumns objRange2,1,1,False,False,False,False,False,False,Array(1, 2),True
```

Comment: Would start by reading through the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.TextToColumns), specifically the `FieldInfo` parameter description. Note: "this argument is an array of two-element arrays", so not `Array(1, 2)` as that is an array of two elements. Maybe try `Array(Array(1, 2))`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, i've changed it! The code runs but does not perform the text to columns function and is also not throwing an error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Already provided my thoughts. you should have enough there to go on. Suggest you [edit] the question to update the code you are now trying. How do you know the `TextToColumns()` method isn't running? If it didn't run I'd expect an error, so the fact you don't receive an error suggests it did run but you didn't get the result you expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBS to split one column in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952693/vbs-to-split-one-column-in-two-columns)